# Return a char pointer (memory leak)

Tags: c++, gcc

I have a function in my hardware code that returns a char* as such:

```
char* getText();
```

I would like to know how this is actually working in the system. In my `getText function`, I allocated a memory space via `alloc to a char*`. Then, I simply returned it through that function.

NOW, I had another function retreive this by calling `char* receive=getText()`, and I deleted receive after making use of it. Can I check if this would causes any memory leak?

Comment: why not use std::string instead?

Comment: You can use Valgrind to check for memory leaks. Using `std::string` is better however.

Comment: This is precisely why raw pointers should *only* be used for observing with no ownership. Simply return (and use) a `std::string` in your case.

Comment: It is indeed C way, not C++. Consider using `std::string`

Comment: Did you mean `new` where you wrote `alloc`? In that case, yes, you can delete the pointer with `delete`. One `delete` for every `new`. However, assuming you're using C and not C++, and you meant `malloc`, you should use `free` on the allocated pointer (receive) and you'd be fine. One `free` per `malloc`.

Comment: Your description is a bit vague. To get an answer that matches your intention you should post the code to allocate the memory, the code to free the memory and probably code that shows the lifetime of the pointer in the consumer.

Comment: Can you provide the exact allocation and deallocation statements? For instance, `new` requires `delete`, `new []` requires `delete []`, and in C `malloc` requires `free`.

Answer (score 2):

Since I assume you are on a linux system using GCC to compile you could use valgrind to run your program and guarantee to find any leaks present or even possible memory leaks that could happen.

To answer your question more directly in this specific case, if you can guarantee that you free() receive after you are done using it then you will not have a memory leak. However, if you forget to free() receive and then reassign something to receive, that right there is considered a memory leak. You have lost the handle to the resource you were responsible for freeing and it can no longer be freed.

In general, your code is very C-like and not the C++ way of doing things. Returning a std::string would be more C++-like. In regards to dynamic allocation, malloc() and free() are also the "C way" of doing dynamic allocation. new and delete are the C++ way of doing dynamic allocation.

Answer (score 2):

As people suggest you, use `std::string` instead of C-like strings. `std::string` manages automatically its own memory, and has a rich and secure interface. String is moveable by default, so by-value-return does not have any performance penalty.

But if you want to return a pointer (In other words, you want  to return a "handle" to the string, not the string itself), consider to use smart-pointers instead of raw-pointers. Smart pointers are leak-free, because its memory magnament is based on [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization). 
The problem with returning a raw-pointer is that the interface of your function not specifies who would deallocate the string. The caller, or a manager/factory that is used by the function?

If you use unique_ptr as return type, you are specifying that the result string will be deleted when the caller stop using its handle. On the other hand, if you use shared_ptr, you specifies that the string is managed by an internal manager/factory used by the function.

The point with smart pointers is that ***you do not have to worry about string lifetime/memory magnament***.